# Is calling start() on a object of this class safe? An example from Java Concurrency in practice

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety, safe-publication

First off, I will give links to the source code that I will be talking about since copy/paste would make this question page too long.

In Listing 5.15 http://jcip.net/listings/CellularAutomata.java of JCIP, I imagine that in some main method, one will create a CellularAutomata object and then call start() on that object.

However, is it okay to do so? When the object's start method is called, it will create N(number of processors) threads with instances of Worker. It seems though that the N threads that are created with the worker object might be seeing a incomplete reference or object of that Worker.

The reasoning behind it is that, the **this** reference escapes during the construction of the CellularAutomata object when calling 
new Runnable() and new Worker(mainBoard.getSubBoard(count, i))

And since Worker[] workers; and CyclicBarrier barrier; are fields of the CellularAutomata object, the threads created in the start() method of that object might not be able to see those objects in a proper state.

I am thinking this is similar to the Holder's example http://jcip.net/listings/StuffIntoPublic.java
http://jcip.net/listings/Holder.java
where the Holder's field might not be visible by other threads.
I understand that the Holder example was problematic because the field was not final, and therefore might not be visible, and in the CellularAutomata   they are final. I read that class with only final fields are guaranteed visibility for their fields when published. However, I also read that although final fields might be the only fields of a class, if the class is not properly constructed, then that guarantee is gone. And in this example, since the **this** reference escapes, I assume it is not properly constructed. Here is an example of implicitly letting the **this** reference escape which is similar to what's going on in CellularAutomata. http://jcip.net/listings/ThisEscape.java

Please let me know if my thoughts need correction, I would really appreciate it. This concurrency journey has been filling me with so many doubts and questions and if you have any other references to where I can learn concurrency and the foundations for concurrency in Java, please let me know.

Thank you

Comment: You can probably discuss with your classmates :-) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47986235/is-concurrency-in-practice-listing-5-15-broken#comment82941527_47986235

Comment: Oh my goodness xD... Well the thing is, that person is me, but I dont know the password to that account... So once I got home, I couldnt log in on my pc. Haha I recognized your name from earlier :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the relevant section the Java Language Specification: [17.5. final Field Semantics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5)

The first relevant section (emphasis added by me):

> An object is considered to be completely initialized when its
>   constructor finishes. **A thread that can only see a reference to an
>   object after that object has been completely initialized** is guaranteed
>   to see the correctly initialized values for that object's final
>   fields.

The `this` references is not seen by any other thread before the constructor completes, so it's fine. 
There is nothing magic about the `this` reference "escaping" from the constructor; the relevant thing is that **no other thread should see it** (before the constructor completes).

The next paragraph in the JLS expands on this (emphasis and italics added by me):

> The usage model for final fields is a simple one: Set the final fields
>   for an object in that object's constructor; and **do not write a
>   reference to the object being constructed in a place *where another
>   thread can see it* before the object's constructor is finished**. If this
>   is followed, then when the object is seen by another thread, that
>   thread will always see the correctly constructed version of that
>   object's final fields.

Comment: This totally corrects me of the wrong thoughts I had about proper initialization and publication. Thank you and also like how you included the JLS important bits

Answer (score 2):

The danger in allowing `this` to escape is that it might be seen before it's fully constructed. In this case, that's not an issue because the runnable doesn't execute until `start()` is invoked, which must be after the constructor completes.

Furthermore, besides the `final` field guarantees, there are at least two additional *happens-before* barriers between the assignment of `mainBoard` and the execution of the runnable. One is the call to `Thread.start()` by what will be [the last thread entering the barrier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html#CyclicBarrier-int-java.lang.Runnable-), which [*happens-before* any action in the started thread.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility) Then there is the actual call to `CylicBarrier.await()`, which [*happen[s]-before* actions that are part of the barrier action](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html#CyclicBarrier-int-java.lang.Runnable-).

So I would say the code is pretty safe.

Comment: Thank you so much shmosel! I wish I can press the up button but dont have enough reputation points. You also answered my question and my doubts and incorrect thoughts about proper initialization and publication